# C#: Pass string to function below

Tags: c#

How do we pass string content to "comparer" function below?

```
public static void Sort(XmlNodeList nodes, Comparison<XmlElement> comparer)
{
    // The nodes.Count == 0 will break the nodes[0].ParentNode,
    // the nodes.Count == 1 is pure optimization :-)
    if (nodes.Count < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    var parent = nodes[0].ParentNode;
    var list = new List<XmlElement>(nodes.Count);
    foreach (XmlElement element in nodes)
    {
        list.Add(element);
    }
    list.Sort(Comparer);
    foreach (XmlElement element in list)
    {
        // You can't remove in the other foreach, because it will break 
        // the childNodes collection
        parent.RemoveChild(element);
        parent.AppendChild(element);
    }
}

public static int Comparer(XmlElement a, XmlElement b,str strAttributeName)
{
    int aaa = int.Parse(a.Attributes["aa"].Value);
    int aab = int.Parse(b.Attributes["aa"].Value);
    int cmp = aaa.CompareTo(aab);
    if (cmp != 0)
    {
        return cmp;
    }
    int ba = int.Parse(a.Attributes["b"].Value);
    int bb = int.Parse(b.Attributes["b"].Value);
    cmp = ba.CompareTo(bb);
    return cmp;
}
```

Here I want to make `a.Attributes["aa"].Value` as `a.Attributes[strAttributeName].Value` in my above code to make it more generic. How do we do it?

Please help.

Comment: Exactly how you did it? `a.Attributes[strAttributeName].Value`. The type of course should be `string` and not `str`.

Comment: Well for starters, you could change `str strAttributeName` to `string strAttributename`... the former won't even compile. What exactly is your question? You can't figure out how to pass a string into a function?

Comment: By `Comparer`, are you aiming to implement the [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IComparer.aspx) interface with a `Compare` method? If so, there is no way to change the number of arguments that go into it =/

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to make your `Comparer` function more generic by adding the XML attribute name as a parameter. However, doing that changes the signature of the function so it no longer matches the signature of the delegate required by [`List.Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).

Fortunately, you can replace `list.Sort(Comparer)` with a lambda which allows you to pass additional parameters to the function `Comparer`. To pass `"aa"` as the attribute name:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => Comparer(a, b, "aa"));
```

To pass `"b"` as the attribute name:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => Comparer(a, b, "b"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int Comparer(XmlElement a, XmlElwment b, string strAttributeName)
```

Comment: I think that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
string strAttributeName = "aa"; //Or dynamically set the value
list.Sort((a, b) => Comparer(a, b, strAttributeName));
```

Furthermore you will need to correct your Copare-method to

```
public static int Comparer(System.Xml.XmlElement a, System.Xml.XmlElement b,
    string strAttributeName)
```

since "str" is not valid in C#.